# github action - trigger the workflow only when there is a change in files in .github/workflows/

Tags: github, github-actions

I need github workflow to be triggered only when there is a change in files in .github/workflows/*. It shouldn't trigger the workflow if the there is a change in any other files.

For e.g., if I make change in the Docker file, the workflow shouldn't trigger.

My branch looks like this:
[image]

My workflow yaml look like this

```
on: 
  #[push]
  pull_request:
    branches:    
      - test  
    types:
      - closed
    #paths-ignore:
    #  - '.github/*'
    paths:
      - '.github/*'
```

The above yaml is not working for what I desire.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that the workflow trigger configurations (the `on` field) doesn't exactly work as you expect.

According to [the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-multiple-events):

> **If you specify multiple events, only one of those events needs to occur to trigger your workflow.** If multiple triggering events for your workflow occur at the same time, multiple workflow runs will be triggered.

Therefore, in your case, each subtype in the `pull_request` event is considered as a separate event, and would trigger the workflow even if the conditions of the other subtypes aren't met.

What is happening here, is that any PR to the `test` branch triggers the `pull_request: branches: - test` subtype, independently of the `paths: - '.github/*'` configuration (it won't matter which file you update if the branch is `test`).

Moreover, with those configurations, the workflow would also trigger if you updated the `'.github/*'` path when opening a PR from another branch.

---

**Summarizing, with your current configurations:**

- open PR from branch `test`: the workflow will trigger.
- open PR from a branch which is not `test`: the workflow will trigger only if there are changes in the path is `'.github/*'`
- close any PR: the workflow will trigger.

---

If you want the workflow to trigger only when there are changes to the specific path, when opening a PR, you should use:

```yaml
on: 
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - '.github/workflows/*'
```

*(Without configuring any other event.)*

Now, if you want the workflow to trigger each time there is a push to a branch (when you open OR update a PR for example), you should use:

```yaml
on: 
  push:
    paths:
      - '.github/workflows/*'
```

Comment: to doublecheck the snippet below will be triggered using OR logic instead of AND that someone would expect?


on:
  # Run workflow file whenever a pull request is opened, or a commit is pushed to it.
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize]
    paths:
      - 'somepath/**'

Comment: It seems the `synchronize` event should be triggered when a pull request's head branch is updated. _For example, when the head branch is updated from the base branch, when new commits are pushed to the head branch, or when the base branch is changed._ So your workflow should trigger if there is a PR opened OR if the PR head branch is updated. [reference](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24567)